# php fsockopen fgets become too slow

Tags: php, performance, header, fgets, fsockopen

I got a problem when I was trying to use fsockopen and fgets to get the content of a web page. I can easily receive the header from the web server as follow:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[cache-control] => private 
[content-type] => text/plain; charset=utf-8 
[server] => Microsoft-IIS/7.0
[x-aspnet-version] => 2.0.50727
[x-powered-by] => ASP.NET
[date] => Sat, 23 Jul 2011 10:36:57 GMT
[connection] => close
[content-length]=> 30072 
[vary] => Accept-Encoding [content-encoding] => gzip
```

My code is as follow:

```
$fp = @fsockopen(“www.abc.com”, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
fwrite($fp, $request);//$request is my predefined header including path and cookies
$lines=””;
while (!feof($fp)) 
{
  Echo “fgets start at ”.date(“H:i:s”).”\n”;
  $line = fgets($fp, 4096);
  Echo strlen($line) .”\n”;
  Echo “fgets end at ”.date(“H:i:s”) .”\n”;
  $lines +=$line;
}
fclose($fp);
```

the output was like that:

```
……
fgets start at 12:23:45
219
Fgets end at 12:23:47
……
```

I am really wondering why it takes 2 seconds to get just 219 byte data.it is just too slow.
To get the whole page,including hundreds of fgets iteration, it spends 40 seconds. Whereas if you use firefox, it just a second..

I want to know what causes the fgets become too slow.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Hmm, how much time takes `file_get_contents("www.abc.com")`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @cn2500 ?

Answer (score 1):

out of the top my head: is it possible that the connection is kept open because you're using a HTTP/1.1 request? this would make the server wait for you to make another request, *then* close the connection if none found (taken as a timeout). besides that, your operating system might be buffering the data (SO_RCVLOWAT socket_option) so the read ends when the web server closes the connection.

try reducing the amount of data to be read (like 128 bytes) inside a loop, and see what happens. other than that (and related to this), you might want to try reading this: http://ar.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings

php might not be reading well the EOL's